# What does R mean in this equation.

Tags: tensors

I have encountered an equation of ([zeppelin](https://nbviewer.org/github/AthenaEPI/dmipy/blob/master/examples/example_gaussian_models.ipynb) = a tensor with the same perpendicular eigenvalues (l2=l3) ) that is simple but I don't understand the operation R. the equation is for implementing Zepplin diffusion in diffusion-weighted MRI. the b is a constant value lambda_par and the lambda_per are eigenvalues of the zeppelin.

anyone can help me?

[image]

to understand better lets think that lambda_par = d_par and lambda_perp = d_perp1=d_perp2 , then the inside of bracetes should be
[image]

what operation makes inside parentheses to below formula?

Comment: I imagine that if you provide some context… the answers will be  facilitated !

Comment: Give definitions of all of the symbols.

Comment: I'd expect $\mathbf R$ to be a rotation matrix.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I agree, it’s not only suggested by the letter itself, but by the fact that in this case it would be $RDR^T = RDR^{-1}$ which, as a basis transformation, looks natural to me.

Comment: It took me a little while to understand that you are looking for the equation of an ellipsoid with implicit equation $\exp(b X^T A X)$ = constant, with equal second and third eigenvalues explaining the "sausage like" = zeppelin form...

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net,  I added a hyperlink in the zeppelin

Comment: @Ehsan Welcome. Adding a link, as you did for mathcounterexamples.net, is good, but your post is still very barebones, so to speak. It is hard to answer such a brief question; despite the link, you nonetheless should fill it out with explanations of the motivation and notation, etc.

Comment: @AndreasBlass is it common in math to write R as rotation?

Comment: @Ehsan Fairly common, but not so common that it's a standard notation usable without explanation.

Comment: @chickenNinja123 based on your comment and others I conclude that its transformation basis and R is the Rotation matrix